# How to unhighlight after searching in evil mode?

Tags: spacemacs, evil

I have a text file opened in Spacemacs with evil mode on. When I search for a term by means of `/term` `[Enter]` then found "term"s are highlighed.

How do I remove that highlighting? I tried `/` `[Enter]` - that didn't work. The highlighting will stick around even after switching to insert mode.

Comment: [This thread](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/2719) might interest you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can achieve the same as entering `:noh` with the command `evil-ex-nohighlight`.

But since you are using spacemacs, it can be even simpler: hit `SPC s c` to clear highlights.

Comment: `SPC s c` is what I was looking for - thanks

Comment: An alternative is `/ ESC`.

Answer (score 4):

Do it just like you would do in Vim (I've checked, `/ RET` doesn't work with `:set hlsearch`), use `:noh`.

Comment: can I make this permanent by adding it to .spacemacs?

Comment: I don't understand. `:noh` is a command you execute to undo highlights. The next time you search, you get the results highlighted. Are you looking for something to prevent search highlights?

Comment: let's say I hoped for something more ergonomic than having to enter :noh after using highlighting. but :noh will do the trick.

Comment: That's fine, I'm asking about your intention. You do understand that a search will highlight the results unless configured otherwise, don't you?

Comment: Is there a way of having the highlights go away after a few seconds of performing a search?

Comment: I cannot reproduce that behavior, might be a Spacemacs thing.

Answer (score 0):

With the idea that @EFLS mentioned, I added these lines to my `.spacemacs` file:

```lisp
(defun dotspacemacs/init ()
  (setq-default
;; ... your other settings
;; ----------------------------------
 ;; don't hightlight search / results
   evil-ex-substitute-highlight-all nil
   evil-ex-search-persistent-highlight nil
;; ----------------------------------
;; ... your other settings
))
```